# Vue JS & Google maps. Директивы рендерятся как HTML теги

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Использую библиотеку 2vue-google-maps для Vue. В infoWindow есть кнопка с @click, проблема в том что она рендерится как обычный HTML тег и собственно не работает. Есть обходной путь? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Может с парсингом проблемы. Попробуй не `@click`, a `v-on:click`. Черт знает...

Comment: @AlexSazonov это из за Google Maps API. Эту страницу генерирует именно он (там карта), а этот div находится внутри разметки метки. Собсна сам гугл и  читает всё как обычные HTML теги. Читал про forceUpdate, но пока не могу разобраться как правильно его использовать)